How do I interpret this Just Intonation scale?
I understand the concept in terms of whole number division for frequencies in a scale to some degree, but when trying to learn Arnold Dreyblatt's scale (link below), I'm lost as to what the fractions would be. The overtone piece is throwing me off.
https://www.dreyblatt.net/general-information-music#/tuning-system/

You would do well to contact the creator using the form provided on the website. For example, it's not at all clear to me what "These mathematically related overtones are heard as tonal relationships" means, since all overtones are mathematically related and any two pitches have a tonal relationship, but definition.

Thanks for the tip! It's nice to know I'm not the only one perplexed by it.

Aaron's answer suffers from a puzzling error, namely of misstating the ratio between the fifth and first partials (more commonly referred to as "harmonics" because mathematical just intonation invariably assumes harmonic oscillators):

fifth partial will have a frequency ratio of 1/5 relative to the fundamental

In fact, the ratio is 5:1, not 1:5.  For example, if you play A=55 on a harmonic oscillator such as a tuba or bowed contrabass, the second through fifth harmonics are 110, 165, 220, 275.  The ratio between 275 and 55 is 5:1.  Accordingly, octave correction means dividing by the next smaller power of two.
(Because the numbers are greater than two rather than being smaller than one, it does not mean multiplying by the next larger power of two as specified in Aaron's answer.)
Thus, from the given series (adding 11, which as Aaron notes was probably left out by mistake),

1, 33, 35, 9, 77, 5, 81, 21, [11,] 45, 3, 49, 99, 25, 27, 55, 7, 15, 121, 63, (2)

we get the following octave-corrected series:

1, 33:32, 35:32, 9:8, 77:64, 5:4, 81:64, 21:16, [11:8,] 45:32, 3:2, 49:32, 99:64, 25:16, 27:16, 55:32, 7:4, 15:8, 121:64, 63:32, (2)

This of course includes many intervals that will be readily recognizable to those familiar with Pythagorean tuning (9:8, 81:64, 3:2), 5-limit just intonation (5:4, 45:32, 15:8), 7-limit or septimal just intonation (7:4), and so on.
Restating these relative to 64 instead of to 1 gives the following:

64, 66, 70, 72, 77, 80, 81, 84, [88,] 90, 96, 98, 99, 100, 108, 110, 112, 120, 121, 126, (128)

One difference between this approach and the usual "N-limit" approach (where N is a prime number) may be seen in the absence of ratios having prime factors other than two in the denominator.  For example, this scale lacks a pitch with a ratio of 4:3 relative to the root, the fourth degree of the diatonic scale.  The closest is the eighth element, which is 471 cents above the root, so rather flat compared to the just fourth of 498 cents; the next element is either 11:8 (if it's indeed supposed to be included), which at 551 cents is closer to the tritone than to the perfect fourth, or or 45:21 (if 11 was omitted intentionally), which is sharper still at 590 cents and is indeed one of the tritones of 5-limit just intonation.
Another difference is the limitation in the power of prime factors.  For example, there is no way to generate the Pythagorean tritone of 729:512.  (In fact, the first difference is also a limitation of power, because it can be expressed by saying that the factors in question cannot have a negative exponent.)
There is a page at the Xenharmonic wiki calculates absolute frequencies for the scale.  I haven't checked the calculations: https://en.xen.wiki/w/Dreyblatt_tuning_system

For anyone curious, this is the list of cent values from this answer: 0.0, 53.3, 155.1, 203.9, 320.1, 386.3, 407.8, 470.8, [551.3], 590.2, 702.0, 737.7, 755.2, 772.6, 905.9, 937.6, 968.8, 1088.3, 1102.6, 1172.7, (1200.0)

First, and critically, Dreyblatt appears to be confusing "overtone" with "partial".1 The first "partial" is the fundamental pitch; the first "overtone" (the second partial) is one octave above the fundamental pitch.
What Dreyblatt is (appears to be) saying is:

From the harmonic series, take partials 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, and 11.
From those six numerical positions in the series, calculate further positions in the series by multiplying each possible pair of numbers. Dreyblatt shows these as a square, but all that's needed is a triangle.




1
3
5
7
9*
11




3
9*
15
21
27
33


5

25
35
45
55


7


49
63
77


9



81
99


11




121



* Note that 9 appears twice.

Using this set of numbers as partials, "octave correct" each pitch. That is, bring each partial within the range of a single octave (i.e., a frequency ratio between 1/1 and 1/2). This amounts to multiplying each frequency (ratio) by 1/2n for some suitable n. For example, the fifth partial will have a frequency ratio of 5/1 relative to the fundamental. Multiplying by 1/23 gives 5/8.

Dreyblatt claims that by doing this, the octave-corrected partials create the following scale (omitting partial 11, presumably by mistake).


1, 33, 35, 9, 77, 5, 81, 21, 45, 3, 49, 99, 25, 27, 55, 7, 15, 121, 63, (2)
Testing the first few terms after the fundamental, we have

33/(2^6)/33 = 33/64 = 33/64
35/(2^6)/35 = 35/64 = 35/64
9/(2^4)/9   =  9/16 = 36/64

So, it seems so far to be a correct ordering. Let's check a few terms from the other end.

 63/(2^6) =  63/64  = 126/128
121/(2^7) = 121/128 = 121/128
 15/(2^4) =  15/16  = 120/128

So, short of checking every term (homework for the class), Dreyblatt has created a microtonal scale.

1 I base this on the fact that the ordering doesn't make sense when based on overtones. For example, the 15th and 63rd overtones (16th and 64th partials) are the same pitch class as the fundamental. Thus, the ordering 15, 121, 63 can't be correct. Further, the 27th and 55th overtones (28th and 56th partials) are also the same pitch class as each other.

This looks great. I never would've got there. I'm going to give it a shot tomorrow.

Do you have a reference for this definition of "partial"?  I don't doubt that it's correct, but I don't recall seeing it used (much less defined) in a formal context.  Perhaps this is because I haven't read enough recently about bell design.

"it seems so far to be a correct, but backwards, ordering": because you have applied the octave correction incorrectly.  This seems to be a consequence of the error in point 3 of the numbered paragraphs.

@phoog I'm not seeing the problem. Please explain further.

@Aaron see my answer.  The first two paragraphs describe the error.

@Aaron look at it this way: the fifth and 81st harmonics of F should give A (in 5-limit or Pythagorean tuning), so if your fundamental is F at 349.23 Hz (as Dreyblatt's is) then the pitch generated by the fifth harmonic should give something roughly 14 cents below 440 and that from the 81st harmonic roughly 8 cents above.  Your calculation gives 558.77 and 551.87; the correct calculation gives 436.54 and 441.99.  You can use the same approach with other well known harmonics such as 3 and 9, which should yield C (2 cents sharper than equal) and G (four cents sharper than equal), respectively.

@phoog The problem is that I flipped the ratios upside down. Just haven't had time to fix it yet.

The math is still wrong.  The power of two should be the next smaller rather than the next larger, so the value of the ratio is between 1 and 2, not between 1/2 and 1.

Oy, vey! Well, at least the ordering is right. Will get to correcting the exponents....
